# How to use python-requests and event hooks to write a web crawler with a callback function?

Tags: python, callback, web-scraping, python-requests

I've recently taken a look at the [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) module and I'd like to write a simple web crawler with it. Given a collection of start urls, I want to write a Python function that searches the webpage content of the start urls for other urls and then calls the same function again as a callback with the new urls as input, and so on. At first, I thought that [event hooks](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks) would be the right tool for this purpose but its documentation part is quite sparse. On [another page](http://notebook.okfn.org/2011/10/08/implementing-an-http-cache-using-requests-api-hooks/) I read that functions which are used for event hooks have to return the same object that was passed to them. So event hooks are obviously not feasible for this kind of task. Or I simply didn't get it right...

Here is some pseudocode of what I want to do (borrowed from a pseudo Scrapy spider):

```
import lxml.html    

def parse(response):
    for url in lxml.html.parse(response.url).xpath('//@href'):
        return Request(url=url, callback=parse)
```

Can someone give me an insight on how to do it with python-requests? Are event hooks the right tool for that or do I need something different? (**Note:** Scrapy is not an option for me due to various reasons.) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_urls_from_response(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    urls = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
    return urls


def print_url(args):
    print args['url']


def recursive_urls(urls):
    """
    Given a list of starting urls, recursively finds all descendant urls
    recursively
    """
    if len(urls) == 0:
        return
    rs = [grequests.get(url, hooks=dict(args=print_url)) for url in urls]
    responses = grequests.map(rs)
    url_lists = [get_urls_from_response(response) for response in responses]
    urls = sum(url_lists, [])  # flatten list of lists into a list
    recursive_urls(urls)
```

I haven't tested the code but the general idea is there.

Note that I am using [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) instead of `requests` for performance boost. `grequest` is basically `gevent+request`, and in my experience it is *much* faster for this sort of tasks because of you retrieve links asynchronous with `gevent`.

---

Edit: here is the same algorithm without using recursion:

```
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_urls_from_response(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    urls = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
    return urls


def print_url(args):
    print args['url']


def recursive_urls(urls):
    """
    Given a list of starting urls, recursively finds all descendant urls
    recursively
    """
    while True:
        if len(urls) == 0:
            break
        rs = [grequests.get(url, hooks=dict(args=print_url)) for url in urls]
        responses = grequests.map(rs)
        url_lists = [get_urls_from_response(response) for response in responses]
        urls = sum(url_lists, [])  # flatten list of lists into a list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recursive_urls(["INITIAL_URLS"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong but you are not using callbacks here but just a simple recursive function call. Doesn't that lead to problems when a certain recursion depth has been reached? As far as I know, Python has not been optimized for recursion, so your setup is likely to throw a `RuntimeError` at some point or am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterStahl You are right, it will only recurse at most `sys.getrecursionlimit()` which is 1000 on my box. I will try to come up an answer that doesn't have this limitation if needed.

Comment: That would be nice, indeed, because this is the main problem that I have. I think I need parallel programming for that but I have no experience with it. Would be nice if you came up with something because I don't really know where to start (using threads or processes, an external library such as Celery etc.). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterStahl No problem, I've added the same code without using recursion. I haven't dug into how to use workers with `grequests`, I suppose that's a different question to ask though.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) OMG, a while loop. It's so simple indeed. I could have come up with that myself. Oh dear, I still have to learn a lot. But that's great for a start and all I wanted to know. :)

Comment: @PeterStahl Glad to help :) Yes recursion and while loops are algorithmically interchangeable. I also played around with the hooks but couldn't quite get it right. I will update again if I get anything out of it.