# Speed up web-scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a project where I have to scrape all the ratings of 50 actors/actresses, which means I have to access and scrape around 3500 web pages. This takes way longer than I expected and I'm looking for a way to speed up things. I know there are frameworks like scrapy, but I'd like to work without any other modules. Is there a fast and easy way to rewrite my code, or would this take too much time?
My code is as follows:

```
    def getMovieRatingDf(movie_links):

        counter = -1
        movie_name = []
        movie_rating = []
        movie_year = []

        for movie in movie_links.tolist()[0]:
            counter += 1

            request = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/' + movie_links.tolist()[0][counter])
            film_soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

            if (film_soup.find('div', {'class': 'title_wrapper'}).find('a').text).isdigit():
            movie_year.append(int(film_soup.find('div', {'class': 'title_wrapper'}).find('a').text))

            # scrap the name and year of the current film
            movie_name.append(list(film_soup.find('h1'))[0])

            try:
                movie_rating.append(float(film_soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'ratingValue'}).text))

           except AttributeError:
                movie_rating.append(-1)
      else:
        continue

      rating_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"movie name": movie_name, "movie rating": movie_rating, "movie year": movie_year})
      rating_df = rating_df.sort_values(['movie rating'], ascending=False)

return rating_df
```

Comment: You seem to have erratic indentation, and Python, of all programming languages, does not like erratic indentation.  Does what you pasted work?  The `return` doesn't belong to the `def` shown.  The `else: continue` and following lines are not correctly indented either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main bottleneck is easy to determine by just looking at the code. It is of a **blocking nature**. You don't download/parse the next page until the current is being processed.

If you want to speed things up, do it *asynchronously in a non-blocking manner*. This is what [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) offers out-of-the-box:

> Here you notice one of the main advantages about Scrapy: requests are
>   scheduled and processed asynchronously. **This means that Scrapy doesn’t
>   need to wait for a request to be finished and processed, it can send
>   another request or do other things in the meantime**. This also means
>   that other requests can keep going even if some request fails or an
>   error happens while handling it.

Another option would be to switch from `requests` to [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests), sample code can be found here:

- [How to use python-requests and event hooks to write a web crawler with a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237587/how-to-use-python-requests-and-event-hooks-to-write-a-web-crawler-with-a-callbac)

---

We can also improve couple things at the HTML-parsing stage:

- switch to [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) from `html.parser` (requires `lxml` [to be installed](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)):

  ```
  film_soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
  ```
- use [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to *parse only the relevant part of the document*